# Distributed Database Communication

Tags: sql-server, web-services, distributed-objects

I am a junior software engineer,I like this site and people in it.So,I want to ask my problems to see your answers and suggestions.Then,please don't mad at me for asking without searching.

My problem is about Distributed database communication(MSSQL Server 2008).In picture,I need a Main Server in center of star topology and other small servers  that holding less data than center.Small servers job is normal web service with small database changes.On the other hand,Main Server should communicate with others periodicly(Once in hour,or twice in a day) and gather distrubited data changes in other small databases.

According to this plan,Main server is trustable,secured and backed up.Here is my question:
I plan to communicate on web services level.Main server should have a methods for controlling and checking databases.Is there any tools for this usage?I am looking forward to your suggestions,visions.

my kind regards and thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SQL Server Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx). From the description you have provided, it sounds as though a solution using remote Subscribers that utilise Push updates could provide the functionality you require.

In the first instance, and in the interest of broadening your knowledge, I suggest you familiarise yourself with the varying flavours of solution that are available to you through [SQL Server Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) technology and study their corresponding architectures.

Comment: @scratmiller: You're welcome. For a history lesson, you may also want to research Federated Databases.